# "could not open lock file: Permission denied" when branching a project

Tags: maven, jenkins, file-permissions, cvs, maven-release-plugin

We're trying to automate our build with the Maven release plugin. We are using Jenkins and CVS too.

Unfortunately we get an error when branching the project:

```
[INFO] Branching release with the label test_branch_jenkins...
[INFO] Executing: /bin/sh -c cd "/data/jenkins/jenkinshome/workspace/Test release plugin  with test project/our-project-parent" && cvs -z3 -f -q tag -b -F -c test_branch_jenkins
[INFO] Working directory: /data/jenkins/jenkinshome/workspace/Test release plugin  with test project/our-project-parent
[…]
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.0:branch (default-cli) on project our-project-parent: Unable to branch SCM
[ERROR] Provider message:
[ERROR] The cvs branch command failed.
[ERROR] Command output:
[ERROR] cvs [tag aborted]: 
    could not open lock file `/srv/cvsrepo/our-project-parent/our-project-frontend/src/main/resources/META-INF/,MANIFEST.MF,':
        Permission denied
```

Do you know what the problem could be here? Is it CVS related or rather a problem with the file system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that indeed the write permission on the file system was not granted for this file. Hence the error message `Permission denied`.